# Something is wrong by compilation

Tags: awk

What do I wrong please? I have a code in file

file.awk:

```
BEGIN { CONVFMT="%0.17f" }
/D Format/ { in_f_format=0; next }
/F Format/ { in_f_format=1; next }
in_f_format != 1 { next }
!($1 ~ /^[1-9]/) { next }
$1 == 11 { prt(180,3.141592653589); next }
$1 == 15 { prt(100,1); next }
$1 == 20 { prt(10,1); next }
$1 == 26 { next }
{ prt(1,1) }

function prt(mult, div) {
print trunc($5 * mult / div) ORS trunc($6 * mult / div)
}

function trunc(n, s) {
s=index(n,".")
return (s ? substr(n,1,s+6) : n)
}
```

I write:

```
chmod +x file.awk 
./file.awk
```

to the terminal and I get these mistakes:

```
./file.awk: řádek 1: BEGIN: příkaz nenalezen
./file.awk: řádek 2: /D: Adresář nebo soubor neexistuje
./file.awk: řádek 2: next: příkaz nenalezen
./file.awk: řádek 3: /F: Adresář nebo soubor neexistuje
./file.awk: řádek 3: next: příkaz nenalezen
./file.awk: řádek 4: in_f_format: příkaz nenalezen
./file.awk: řádek 5: chyba syntaxe poblíž neočekávaného tokenu „{“
./file.awk: řádek 5: `!($1 ~ /^[1-9]/) { next }'
```

Where is the mistake please?

**EDIT**
Similarly script

```
BEGIN { CONVFMT="%0.17f" }
/D Format/ { in_f_format=0; next }
/F Format/ { in_f_format=1; next }
in_f_format != 1 { next }
!($1 ~ /^[1-9]/) { next }
$1 == 35 { print t($5), t($6) }

function trunc(n, s) {
s=index(n,".")
return (s ? substr(n,1,s+6) : n)
}
```

Gives an error:

```
fatal: function `t' not defined
```

I would like to write from this input

```
                      Input-Output in F Format

No.  Curve    Input Param.        Correction     Output Param.    Standard Deviation
26      0  56850.9056460000     -0.0017608883  56850.9038851117      0.0016647171
35      1      0.2277000000      0.0011369754      0.2288369754      0.0014780395
35      2      0.2294000000      0.0000417158      0.2294417158      0.0008601513
35      3      0.2277000000      0.0007425066      0.2284425066      0.0022555311
35      4      0.2298000000     -0.0000518690      0.2297481310      0.0010186846
35      5      0.2295000000      0.0000793572      0.2295793572      0.0014667137
35      6      0.2300000000      0.0000752449      0.2300752449      0.0006258864
35      7      0.2307000000     -0.0001442591      0.2305557409      0.0002837569
35      8      0.2275000000      0.0007358355      0.2282358355      0.0007609550
35      9      0.2292000000      0.0003447650      0.2295447650      0.0007148005
35     10      0.2302000000     -0.0001854710      0.2300145290      0.0006320668
35     11      0.2308000000     -0.0002064324      0.2305935676      0.0008911070
35     12      0.2299000000     -0.0000202967      0.2298797033      0.0002328860
35     13      0.2298000000      0.0000464629      0.2298464629      0.0011609539
35     14      0.2307000000     -0.0003654521      0.2303345479      0.0006827961
35     15      0.2294000000      0.0002157908      0.2296157908      0.0003253584


                      Input-Output in D Format
```

numbers that are in $5 and $6 that are in rows starting 35.

**EDIT 2**
I eddited the position of f function like

```
BEGIN { CONVFMT="%0.17f" }
function trunc(n, s) {
s=index(n,".")
return (s ? substr(n,1,s+6) : n)
}
/D Format/ { in_f_format=0; next }
/F Format/ { in_f_format=1; next }
in_f_format != 1 { next }
!($1 ~ /^[1-9]/) { next }
$1 == 35 { print t($5), t($6) }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***UPDATE:*** After chatting with OP(which I mentioned in my comments too) OP needs to change function's name to actual function from `t` and it worked then. Thought to update here so all will know it.

---

---

There could be 2 possible solutions.

***1st:*** Mention `awk` in shellscript and run it as shell script.

```
cat script.ksh
awk 'BEGIN { CONVFMT="%0.17f" }
/D Format/ { in_f_format=0; next }
/F Format/ { in_f_format=1; next }
in_f_format != 1 { next }
!($1 ~ /^[1-9]/) { next }
$1 == 11 { prt(180,3.141592653589); next }
$1 == 15 { prt(100,1); next }
$1 == 20 { prt(10,1); next }
$1 == 26 { next }
{ prt(1,1) }

function prt(mult, div) {
print trunc($5 * mult / div) ORS trunc($6 * mult / div)
}

function trunc(n, s) {
s=index(n,".")
return (s ? substr(n,1,s+6) : n)
}' Input_file
```

Give `script.ksh` proper execute permissions and run it like you are running.

***2nd:*** Run it as a `awk` script by running it like:

```
awk -f awk_file Input_file
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186577/discussion-between-elisabeth-and-ravindersingh13).

Answer (score 2):

The canonical(not sure if it's the right word) way to use it is like this:

```
awk -f file.awk datafile
```

or the pipe way like this:

```
cat datafile | awk -f file.awk
```

The `file.awk`, which is same as your trying, is the awk's script file.(name can change).
And the `datafile` is the file(s) contains the data you want to dealing with.

And no need to chmod awk file(s) to use it.

***Update:***
**But** thanks keith kindly mentioned in comment you can do it like that too.
Put this line:

```
#/usr/bin/awk -f
```

at the beginning of your `file.awk`.(given your `awk` executable is at that location).
After `chmod +x file.awk`, you can execute it like this:

```
./file.awk datafile
```

Comment: Or you can add `#!/usr/bin/awk -f` at the top of the script (and `chmod +x`). That way the user doesn't have to care that it's an awk script rather than shell, python, or a compiled executable. (This assumes `/usr/bin/awk` is the location of the interpreter.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Wow, that's great! I'll try it later and update my answer, thanks a lot :)

Comment: FWIW I would never use a shebang to call the awk interpreter as that robs you of the ability to separate the shell script arguments into awk variables and awk arguments, e.g. `shellscript foo bar` -> `awk -v var="$1" 'awkscript' "$2"`. Try doing that simple and common task when `shellscript` uses an awk shebang! If there's any real benefit to using the shebang approach, though, I'm all ears...

Answer (score 2):

Without a shebang line, the shell thinks your script is a shell script. To make it [executable as an awk script](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Executable-Scripts), you have to use the proper shebang line:

```
cat <<'EOF' > awkscript
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { print "Hello, world!" }
EOF
chmod +x awkscript
```

where `/usr/bin/awk` is the path to your awk executable (can be found with `type awk`). The important bit is the `-f` flag.

Now you can run it as a standalone script:

```
$ ./awkscript 
Hello, world!
```